# Error while creating database on OrientDB

Tags: database, orientdb

When I use the following command to create a database in OrientDB 2.0.10,

```
CREATE DATABASE plocal:../databases/pincode admin admin plocal
```

I get the following error.

```
Creating database [plocal:../databases/pincode] using the storage type [plocal]...
Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ODatabaseException: Cannot create database 'pincode'
Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.OCommandExecutorNotFoundException:Cannot find a command executor for the command request: sql.select count(*) from ORole where name.type() not in ["STRING"] and name is not null
```

I get the same error if i try to create the database this way,

```
CREATE DATABASE remote:localhost/pincode root password plocal
```

I have connected to the remote server in both cases.

Similar error of command executor not found, pops up even when I try to connect to the database.

Can someone help tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Which version of orientdb ?

Comment: And this one? *CREATE DATABASE remote:localhost/pincode root password plocal graph*